# Confusion over execution order

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a game application made up of several different activities. The first to be called is a splash screen, when this completes, this finishes and starts up another activity via an intent. In order to have access to some global data that is consistent across all the activities, I also have a "globals" class like this:

```
public class Globals extends Application
{
  int global_variable_A;
  int global_variable_B;
  int global_variable_C;

  public void onCreate()
  {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

In the androidmanifest.xml I have the the following (amongst other things):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/mygame_icon"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label='"My Game"' android:name=".Globals">

<activity
    android:label="My Game"
    android:name=".Splash" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My question now is, which will be executed first, the onCreate of Globals or the onCreate of Splash? Or are they run at the same time on different threads? I ask because I'm getting some inconsistent behaviour that would be explained if they were on different threads.

Comment: The `Globals` would be created first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate()`  Global off course..  Application gets executed first and then the Activity,,.. you can test for yourself by keeping a debug point in Application onCreate() method..